# Git patches and new branch

Tags: git

I have a bunch of files I have made changes to on my local all in one branch say named "test". I want to select specific files and then move them to a new branch and commit them remotely to that new branch.

My boss advised me to run `git commit -p` and then go through what I want to keep and somehow add it to a new branch and push it. I am struggling figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boss's recommended approach only makes sense if you have a mixture of changes for the new branch, and changes for the old branch (or to be discarded, or whatever) *in the same files*.

Assuming that is the case:

1. create & switch to the new branch without changing your working copy:

   ```
   git checkout -b mynewbranch
   ```

   but don't delete anything - that would be potentially lossy at this stage
2. add any new (un-tracked) files that should exist only on the new branch for now

   ```
   git add <filenames>
   ```
3. add any changes that should go on the new branch

   ```
   git add --patch
   ```

   or

   ```
   git add --interactive
   ```

   I always find *interactive* takes a bit of practise to be honest, it isn't the friendliest interface.
4. commit the index to your new branch - you can review it first to confirm it makes sense

   ```
   git status
   git diff --cached
   git commit
   ```

   note that any changes you chose *not* to add to this branch, will still exist only in your working copy
5. switch back to your previous branch, taking any un-added, un-committed working copy changes with you

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```

Comment: ah very helpful thank you! the use case for patches was what i was struggling with. I think I get it now. thanks!

Comment: You could also use `git stash save --patch` to separate the changes ... but my answer was long enough already.

Answer (score 3):

First switch to a new branch:

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch
```

Then delete all the files you do not want to have in that branch. Once you have done this, run:

```
git add -u
git commit
```

And finally push your new branch to your remote:

```
git push origin mynewbranch
```

Comment: Thank You, what will happen to the files on my original branch?

Comment: Nothing. As long as you commit all your changes before doing this, go you can always go back to your original branch with `git checkout originalbranch`

Comment: this method seems like you risk losing changes you _don't_ want to move onto the new branch

Comment: As long as you commit your changes you never risk loosing anything in git.

Comment: It's the _Then delete all the files ..._ part that worried me - if you want them on the old branch but not the new one, it's too late, you deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, each one with advantages and disadvantages.

### Direct approach

As was described already: switch to another branch, delete files not needed, commit files you need.

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch
git add -u
git commit
git push origin mynewbranch
```

Quick and dirty, but you will loose all history, if these files were changed already.

### Ninja move

You can `stash` your changes from one branch and apply them in another branch.

```
git shash # Will put your changes into `hidden pocket`
git checkout -b mynewbranch
git stash pop # Your changes will pop out from `hidden pocket`
git commit
git push origin mynewbranch
```

Slick and accurate, but you'll still loosing history for these files, if any.

### Bundle approach

You could transfer commits from one branch to another.

```
git bundle file.name revision..list # Packing revisions to file
git checkout -b mynewbranch
git bundle unbundle file.name # Unpacking revision in new branch
```

Slick, keeps your history, but save only if during selected revisions no other files were touched.

### Old school

Use patches!

```
git format-patch revision..list # generate patch files for each revision in the list
git checkout -b mynewbranch
cat filename.patch | git am # Applying patch to the current branch
```

May be complex to figure out which patch you need to apply and which you should not. But  you can take full control on process.

If none of described fits your needs 100%, you could combine approaches to achieve what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

- Not committing the changes yet
- Checking out to a new branch (-b creates a new branch)

  ```
  git checkout -b new_branch
  ```
- Committing the changes in the new branch

  ```
  git commit -a -m "made some changes and stuff"
  ```
- Making the patch

  ```
  git format-patch master --stdout > made_some_changes.patch
  ```

  This last line creates a new patch file and records all the changes in the new file.

When you create a new branch and with untracked files and changes present, the original branch goes back to its last commit and all the untracked changes are visible only in the new branch and not the old one.

For suaveness: naming the patch file `../made_some_changes.patch` will create the file outside of your repository. So the command would be

```
git format-patch master --stdout > ../made_some_changes.patch
```